# Bloom Filter, Simple C++ Implementation

Tags: c++, bloom-filter

So, I'm coding a simple Bloom filter. Current implementation works as expected, but I'm looking for ways to improve efficiency / speed. The code is being tested on a large chunk of data (~30k+ lines), so every little bit counts.

> Also: Is there any way I can initialize a vector only one time, not using `resize()`?

```
set() computes number of hashes and size of bit array
add() adds element to filter
search() gives an approximate answer, if filter contains element or not
print() prints bit array
```

`main()` mostly contains parsing

Here is the test example: https://pastebin.com/3edmX2vH

Here is the code itself:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

const unsigned long M = 2147483647; 

const unsigned long long Primes[] =
{
    0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 
    89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113,    127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 
    181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281
};

template <class T>
class Filter 
{
    std::vector<bool> bits;
    size_t size;
    size_t numHashes;

    size_t getHash(const T& key,const size_t& hashIndex);

public:
    Filter() {};
    ~Filter() {};

    bool Set(const int& n, const double& p);
    void Add(const T& key);
    void Print(); 
    bool Search(const T& key);
};

template <class T>
bool Filter<T>::Set(const int& n, const double& prob)
{
    size = round((-n * log2(prob)) / log(2));
    numHashes = round(-log2(prob));
    if (size == 0 || numHashes == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        bits.resize(size);
        std::cout << size << " " << numHashes << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
template <class T>
void Filter<T>::Add(const T& key)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numHashes; i++)
    {
        size_t index = getHash(key, i);
        bits[index] = true; 
    }
}

template <class T>
bool Filter<T>::Search(const T& key)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numHashes; i++)
    {
        size_t index = getHash(key, i);
        if (!bits[index]) 
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template <class T>
void Filter<T>::Print()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << bits[i];
    }
    std:: cout << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
size_t Filter<T>::getHash(const T& key, const size_t& hashIndex)
{
    return (((hashIndex + 1) * (key % M) + Primes[hashIndex + 1]) % M) % size;
}


int main()
{
    Filter<uint64_t> filter;
    std::string command, line;
    uint64_t element;
    double prob;

    bool setFlag = false;
    bool empty = false;  
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream is(line);
        if (is.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0)
        {
            empty = true;
        }
        command.clear();
        is >> command >> element >> prob;
        if (command == "set")
        {
            if (!setFlag && element != 0 && prob != 0 && prob < 1)
            {
                setFlag = filter.Set(element, prob);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == "add")
        {
            is >> element;
            if (is.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0 && setFlag)
            {

                filter.Add(element);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == "search")
        {
            is >> element;
            if (is.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0 && setFlag)
            {
                std::cout << filter.Search(element) <<std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == "print" && setFlag)
        {
            if (is.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0)
            {
                filter.Print();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!empty)
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiom for setting a vector contained in a class is

```
Filter::Filter( int s ) : bits( vector<bool>(s) ) { ... };
```

In your case `s` is somewhat tricky, so you'll have to write a function for it.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor things that will improve just a bit, you should precomputed the value of log(2) and put as a constant if is not precomputed by the compiler, and the increments on your loops should be ++i, instead i++